# I need to create report from external sql database , and run the report at sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, library, database, sql, external

I need to create a report from an external SQL database and run the report at SharePoint 2016. The SQL database size was big around 5 GB, How can  I do it?
I think to create a procedure at SQL database level to read external bulk data and then create the report at SharePoint.
There are only Library Report, Are there any solution to generate and run a report at SharePoint

Answer (score 0):

Consider using SQL Server Reporting Services:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/create-a-report-or-a-scorecard-sharepoint-server-1b0cff41-d6a6-47ae-a908-8fa1b4ca4379

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reports/reporting-services-reports-ssrs?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/reporting-services-tools?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15